# FB.Event.subscribe comment - catch the reply event

Tags: javascript, facebook

I use facebook comments on my page, and I save the comments in database.

```
...    
FB.Event.subscribe("comment.create", function(response) {
        // SAVE
    });
...
```

When someone responds to a comment, the comment.create event dosen't work.
How can I catch the reply events?

thanks
David